# Insert Record into SQL Server with static IP

Tags: c#, sql-server, remote-access

I have a SQL Server database on a remote server which has a static IP address. I want to insert a record from my local computer into my remote server using that static IP address in C#.

How I will make a connection string with the server and insert a record without using API? I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a we-will-write-your-code-for-you-service. Please show what you have tried yourself and where you're stuck.

Comment: just change your connection string accordingly. Refer to https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for further information on connection string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use four part naming  like below

```
insert into [192.16.1.20].[databasename].[schemaname].tablename
select * from tablename
```

Comment: How I will make connection string with remote server on local computer

Comment: try searching for linked servers

Answer (score 0):

First Check your network connection to the IP of server. If the IP was available just create a normal query-string as you do always and in the data source put the IP address.
If it did not work check if the database servers firewall accepts requests on the default port or check if the SQL servers listening port has been changed and does not use the default port anymore.